# WPF set CustomControl style based on custom property's value

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, custom-controls

I have a `CustomControl` with custom property (`DependencyProperty`) which called "SingleRow".
If the property is set to true I need to use specific style.
If the property is set to false I need to use the default style - for that I dont need to do anything special.

here are my styles:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MetroTabControl}">
...
</Style>

<Style x:Key="MetroTabControlSingleRow" TargetType="{x:Type local:MetroTabControl}">
...
</Style>
```

How can I set the `CustomControl` to use the "MetroTabControlSingleRow" when the SingleRow property is true?

I tried:

```
public static DependencyProperty SingleRowPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.Register("SingleRow", typeof(bool), typeof(MetroTabControl), new PropertyMetadata(true));
public bool SingleRow
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(SingleRowPropertyKey); }
    set { base.SetValue(SingleRowPropertyKey, value); }
}

public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    if (SingleRow)
    {
        ResourceDictionary rd = new ResourceDictionary();
        rd.Source = new Uri("/MetroControls;component/Generic.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd);
        SetResourceReference(MetroTabControl.StyleProperty, "MetroTabControlSingleRow");

        Style = (Style)this.FindResource("MetroTabControlSingleRow");
    }
}
```

But it keep crashing.

**Edit:**
Also, based on dev hedgehog's comment, I tried:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MetroTabControl}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="SingleRow" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MetroTabControlSingleRow}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="SingleRow" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MetroTabControlMultiRows}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="MetroTabControlSingleRow" TargetType="{x:Type local:MetroTabControl}">
...
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="MetroTabControlMultiRows" TargetType="{x:Type local:MetroTabControl}">
...
</ControlTemplate>
```

and still crashes.

Would appreciate your help.

Comment: I use a ContentPresenter and a converter, and bind the property the contentemplate of that contenpresenter.

Comment: What crash? Can you be more specific?

Comment: How can I debug design crash? I cant just put try{} catch{} to catch the exception..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use triggers for that.

Here is an example with IsFocused property.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="NotFocused" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">  
    . . .
</ControlTemplate>  

<ControlTemplate x:Key="Focused" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">   
    . . .
</ControlTemplate>


<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">   
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Focused}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NotFocused}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Still crushes. Maybe I didnt define correctly my SingleRow DependencyProperty?

Comment: I found that code on the internet. Its working with IsFocused property. You will not be able to copy past it :) but I hope you get the idea. It will work. Check your spelling and dependency property definitions...

Comment: ofc, I modified it to match my program - see my edit

Comment: You have to change the order of initalization. First come those ControlTemplates and then the Style. Its important to have the right oder of how are objects gonna be created in resources. :) If you still get the error change the name of your dependency property to SingleRowProperty. You dont need the key part.

Comment: Have you changed the name to SingleRowProperty. You dont need the key part.

Comment: Delete your last comment, I had another Resources in the wrong order

Comment: SingleRowProperty doesnt need Key in its name. Thats not matching the naming conventions in wpf. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I use it and it works for me.

Code:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public DataTemplate First { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Second { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value)
            return First;
        else
            return Second;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="first">
    <Button>one</Button>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="second">
    <CheckBox/>
</DataTemplate>

<local:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter"
                   First="{StaticResource first}"
                   Second="{StaticResource second}" />

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl1}">
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl1}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{Binding SingleRow, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: You are binding your ContentPresenter, I dont want to change the templae of the ContentPresenter but its parent